# How to tell apart a `Facebook Group` and a `Facebook Page`?

Tags: facebook

Let's take one example of each:

1. https://www.facebook.com/TimHieuVeChienTranhVietNamVietNamWar
2. https://www.facebook.com/groups/GST.HCM.HCMUT.2014/

How can a normal Facebook user tell which one is a *Facebook Page* and which one is a *Facebook Group*?

Comment: @pnuts Please just put the answer. I'll help to make yours well-prepared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't now that this is conclusive (eg applies in general) but the top right corner of the first link in the OP has:

[image: WA69161 first example]

and the second:

[image: WA69161 second example]

so it seems the `Create Page` or `Join Group` may be the indication required.

Answer (score 2):

The URL starts with `https://www.facebook.com/groups/`

You'll note in your two examples, you have one with the `groups` part of the URL and one without.

Also, once you go to the URL and view it, a page will offer you a like button, whereas a group will offer you a join button.